# .net Framework to .net Core

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Im doing a project with .net Framework , but to run on the linux i need .net Core..

I heard that it is possible to change .net Core to .net Framework only with changes on the project.csproj with this:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
```

to

```
<TargetFramework>v4.5.2</TargetFramework>
```

and i tried to do the opposite , but i got some erros on the project...

There's a way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't dream it, and face the truth. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/mvc

Comment: My project isnt MVC

Comment: If not MVC but WebForms you hit a real dead end. In that case you have to completely rewrite as ASP.NET Core MVC and cut/paste only the useful portion of your old solution. No other way out.

Comment: Thank you very much , i w'll do that !

Answer (score 2):

You can not switch a .NET Framework project to .NET Core that easy. 
You might change an empty project but not one you already started coding.
Possibly you'll need to rewrite or start from scratch.

**There are some major differences between two**

- Format of configuration files *(web.config vs [appsettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration))*

  - See [this post](http://benfoster.io/blog/net-core-configuration-legacy-projects) on providing backward compatibility for App.config, appSettings.config and Web.config XML-based configuration providers
- Used libraries
- Startup files *(Global.asax vs Startup.cs)*
- Lack of static objects in .Net Core. *Like Session and Application objects -
  which is a good thing btw.*
- Many of the .Net Framework libraries are dependant on
  app.config/web.config files